# Upload files to remote server in sailsJS

Tags: node.js, upload, exe, sails.js

I have created a small application using **Node-WebKit**. So I want to write a backend service in **SailsJS** which will help me upload any kind of **.exe** file from my system to a remote server. I would like to know how I can write a service to upload an .exe file to local disk when the remote server location and file to be uploaded locations are specified.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the front end, use a file input to input the file. Then use the following function to upload:

```
/* On the front-end */
function uploadFile() {
  /* Using AJAX */
  var formData = new FormData(),
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  /* Required for large files */
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrfToken);

  formData.append('myFile', inputElement.files[0]);
  formData.append('_csrf', csrfToken);

  xhr.open('POST', sailsRoute, true);
  xhr.send(formData);
  xhr.onload = function(){
    /* callback on upload */
  };
}
```

On the Backend, bind below function to `sailsRoute` and handle file:

```
/* On the Backend */
function (req, res) {
  var packet = req.params.all();
  if (req.files) {
    /* use req.files.myFile.path and fs module to save to disk */
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to figure out how to do this with web sockets and it was killing me.